# Can't mount phone in 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I used to be able to plug my phone in and it would be detected as a 32GB drive that I could copy e.g. music to. Since 12.10 I can't do this (message is that it won't mount the drive 'operation not supported'. Also I can't access my Windows partitions, although I can see them.
Am I missing a setting somewhere? (Linux softie user asking here...)

Answer (score -1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065964

Please add yourself to the support bug issued above.

Comment: By "add yourself", Mattressvon means click "Does this bug affect you?", and click "Yes". Don't post a comment saying "me too", as this is just spam.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because it is not clear from the question that the OP is affected by this bug. It is not even clear what phone the OP is using.